# Positioning a Windows.Controls.Grid in a WPF FlowDocument

Tags: wpf, grid, flowdocument, flowdocumentreader

How can I specify (programmatically) the position of a new grid (created programmatically, see below) within a FlowDocument I have already created via XAML. I want the new grid to show below another Grid I already have in the FlowDocument.

```
Dim myItemsGrid As Windows.Controls.Grid = New Windows.Controls.Grid
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is no way to do this.

The way to go is to use Tables, as these are more compatible with FlowDocuments anyway. The flow document pagination does not truncate grid content as it should, tables however work nicely.